# How to find the frequency response of the Rosenberg Glottal Model

Tags: matlab

Is there an easy way to calculate the frequency response of the following function?

[image]

I tried using heaviside function but with no luck.

Basically I want to write a function to return the frequency response  based on input N1 and N2 and also the number of points (lets say x) between 0 and pi

The output would be a vector which returns x values for the frequency response for corresponding frequencies =>  0:pi/x:pi

Comment: Do you want to find the closed form solution, or do you want to numerically find it?  Numerical is easy.  Simply use that formula and calculate a sequence, then use `fft` on it.  Please be more clear.

Comment: I added some info, let me know if this is clear enough

Comment: I wrote an answer.  Hopefully this will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `N1 + N2 < num_points`, where `num_points` is the length of the sequence, you can simply write the function like so:

```
function [gr] = rosenburg(N1, N2, num_points)
gr = zeros(num_points,1);
range1 = 0:N1;
range2 = N1+1:N1+N2;
gr(range1+1) = 0.5*(1 - cos(pi*range1/N1));
gr(range2+1) = cos(pi*(range2-N1) / (2*N2));
end
```

The function prototype, `rosenburg` takes in `N1`, `N2` and the total number of points you want this function to take in, `num_points`.  How this code works is that we first allocate an array that is all zeroes of size `num_points`.  We then compute two linear ranges:  One from `0 <= n <= N1` and the other from `N1 < n <= N2`.  Note that the second range starts by offsetting `N1` by 1 because we have already computed the value at `n = N1`.  Once we compute these ranges, we simply apply the right relationship in the right ranges.  Note that when I'm assigning the relationships to the correct intervals in the array, I need to offset by 1 because MATLAB begins indexing arrays at index 1.  The rest of the values are zero due to the initialization at the beginning of the function.

Now, if you want to find the frequency response of this signal, just use [`fft`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) which is the [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform).  It's the classic method to find the frequency domain version of a discrete input signal on a numerical basis.  As such, once you create your signal using the `rosenburg` function, then throw this into the FFT function.  How you call it is like so:

```
X = fft(gr);
```

This computes the `N` point FFT, where `N` is the length of the signal `gr`.  Alternatively, you can provide the number of points you want to compute the FFT for.  Specifically:

```
X = fft(gr, N);
```

Basically, the higher `N` is, the finer or granular the frequency components will be.  Note that the frequency axis is normalized between 0 to `2*pi`, and so the higher `N` is, the finer resolution you will have between neighbouring points on the axis.  Specifically, each point on this axis has the following frequency:

```
w = i*(2*pi)/x;
```

`i` would be the index on the `x`-axis (0, 1, 2, ..., num_points-1) and `x` would be the total number of points for the FFT.  Normally, people show the spectrum between `-pi <= w <= pi`, and so some people apply [`fftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) to shift the spectrum so that the DC component is located at the centre of the spectrum, which is how we naturally perceive the spectrum to be.

When you say "frequency response", I believe you are referring to the **magnitude**, and so use [`abs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html) to calculate the complex magnitude of each value, as the `fft` is generally complex valued.  Therefore, assuming that you wish to compute the FFT to be as many points as the length of your signal, and let's say we choose `N1 = 4, N2 = 8` and we want 64 points, and we want to plot the spectrum.  Simply do this:

```
gr = rosenburg(4, 8, 64);
X = fft(gr);
Xshift = fftshift(X);
plot(linspace(-pi,pi,64), abs(Xshift));
grid;
```

The above code will shift the spectrum, then plot its magnitude between `-pi` to `pi`.  This is what I get:

[image]

As an illustration, this is what the spectrum looks like before we apply `fftshift`:

[image]

Here's the code to generate the above figure:

```
plot(linspace(0,2*pi,64), abs(X));
grid;
```

You can see that the spectra is symmetric.  Right at the frequency `pi`, you can see that it is mirror reflected, which makes sense as the range from `pi` to `2*pi`, precisely maps to `-pi` to 0.  Because the signal is real, the spectrum is symmetric.  In fact, we can call this signal [Hermitian symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_function).  Obviously, the frequency components are a bit sparsely spaced.  It may be better to increase the total number of points to something like 256.  This is what I get when I change the number of points to 256:

[image]

Pretty smooth!  Now, if you want to extract the frequency components from 0 to `pi`, you need to extract half of the frequency decomposition that is stored in `X`.  Therefore, you would simply do:

```
f = X(1:numel(X)/2);
```

[`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) determines how many elements are in an array or matrix.   However, remember that each frequency point was defined as:

```
w = i*(2*pi)/x
```

You specifically want:

```
w = i*pi/x
```

As such, you'll need to compute the FFT at **twice** the size of your signal first, then extract half of the spectra in the same way.  For example, for 64 points:

```
gr = rosenburg(4, 8, 64);
X = fft(gr, 128);
f = X(1:numel(X)/2);
```

---

This should hopefully get you started.  Good luck!

Comment: @IsuruDaulagala - My pleasure.  Let me know if that works for you, and if it does, consider accepting my answer.  Good luck!